# Fatal error: Call to undefined function load_theme_textdomain() in /var/www/vhosts/61/151172/webspace/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5

Tags: functions

I am a complete rookie. Tried to hide the tags on my website & saw in a video if I add a code to functions.php it will do the job but instead I got the white screen of death. Oops.

If I replace the function.php file with a fresh Wordpress download file I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in /var/www/vhosts/61/151172/webspace/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1081

I can not log in to back end, don't think I have a backup.

Have access to file manager from cpanel so can do changes to files if needed

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you, Attila

Comment: The fresh file you're uploading definitely isn't fresh as it's got an error in it. You need to find another version of this file, perhaps from backup. have you loked on line 1081 to see what's there, maybe you or someone edited this file?

Comment: if you're not sure what you're looking at in this file paste that line and the lines around it into your question here - maybe there's a quick fix you can make to fix this error if you don't have another copy of this file

Comment: Here's [line 1081 in functions.php in 5.4.2](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L1081): it's the start of the add_query_arg function. Is there any chance you're running PHP 5.5 or earlier which don't support that [variable-length argument list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) syntax, which was new in PHP 5.6?

Comment: But when the video said editing functions.php it meant in a plugin or theme, not in WordPress itself.